# PHP form output multiple fields duplicate

Tags: php, forms

Hello i want to create this array output from FORM post with PHP

[image]

Here my FORM, duplicate with javascript the DIV data with class .duplicated

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<form method='post'>
    <input name='group_name'/>
    <input name='group_'/>
    <div class='duplicated'>
       <input name='group_values[][name]'/>
       <input name='group_values[][price]'/>
    </div>
    <div class='duplicated'>
       <input name='group_values[][name]'/>
       <input name='group_values[][price]'/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This form return this array

[image]

Comment: nikmauro if you got answer then mark the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because a empty bracket like that makes php / html create a new "key/value", make your

```
 <input name='group_values[][name]'/>
 <input name='group_values[][price]'/>
```

Into:

```
<input name='group_values[1][name]'/>
<input name='group_values[1][price]'/>
```

And you should see a difference, if you need it to happen by itself you can use a varaible, set it to 0 or what ever value you want your array to start from, and give it +1 each time you want a new "group" Like so:

```
<?php $i = 0; //Initializes the variable ?>
<input name='group_values[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]'/> //Array key = 0
<input name='group_values[<?php echo $i; ?>][price]'/> //Array key = 0 
<?php $i++; //Increases the variable with 1 ?>
<input name='group_values[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]'/> //Array key = 1
<input name='group_values[<?php echo $i; ?>][price]'/> //Array key = 1
```

Of course it can be done in a more efficient / smarter way, but this is just to give you a basic example

For Javascript it will depend on how you duplicate the data, but the idea is basically the same

```
var key = 0;
var duplicateInput1 = "<input name='group_values[" + key + "][name]'/>"  + 
                     "<input name='group_values[" + key + "][price]'/>";

key++;
var duplicateInput2 = "<input name='group_values[" + key + "][name]'/>"  + 
                     "<input name='group_values[" + key + "][price]'/>";

var duplicateForm = duplicateInput1.concat(duplicateInput2);
```

Comment: The javascript duplicate the form fields and not the PHP